# FABRIK : how to hide elements use dropdown element

Tags: joomla

I have 6 dropdowns in the same group... (doubt, should be in the same group, or selector should be in other group??)

```
dropdown-1 : is a language selector --> with 5 languages, language-1,2,3,4,5

5 others dropdowns.
dropdown-2 for language-1
dropdown-3 for language-2
dropdown-4 for language-3
dropdown-5 for language-4
dropdown-6 for language-5

first thing i'm tying is if dropdown-1 = 0 --> when you "load page" hide all rest of dropdowns
if dropdown-1 = 1 --> show only the dropdown-2 for language-1
if dropdown-1 = 2 --> show only the dropdown-3 for language-2
if dropddown-1 = 3 --> show only the dropdown-4 for language-3
if dropddown-1 = 4 --> show only the dropdown-5 for language-4
if dropddown-1 = 5 --> show only the dropdown-6 for language-5
```

In dropdown-1 in the javascript plugin, I have tried the "load" event and in code JS, just first option, for dropdown-1=0. Hide the others elements and in the last Element pluguin, I selected the group where the dropdown are. The plugin looks like this.

```
[ELEMENT FABRIK PLUGIN][1]
```

But the code doesn´t like (although i use something similar and works in other web) or maybe first dropdown should be out of the group.. but i try, and that didn´t work either.

I have try also, using the USE predefined ACTION.. but i can not hide any element

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cG7D.png)

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I missed `""` when you make the selection.

When I write `if($sel==="0")` the code runs.

The code used in the plugin to hide elements "on load" is:

```
var $sel = this.getValue();
var $esp= Fabrik.getBlock('form_68').formElements.get('cartas_restaurantes___selector_idioma');
var $nom1= Fabrik.getBlock('form_68').formElements.get('cartas_restaurantes___es_selector_carta');
var $nom2= Fabrik.getBlock('form_68').formElements.get('cartas_restaurantes___cat_selector_carta');
var $nom3= Fabrik.getBlock('form_68').formElements.get('cartas_restaurantes___eus_selector_carta');
var $nom4= Fabrik.getBlock('form_68').formElements.get('cartas_restaurantes___gl_selector_carta');
var $nom5= Fabrik.getBlock('form_68').formElements.get('cartas_restaurantes___eng_selector_carta');

if($sel==="0"){
  $nom1.hide();
  $nom2.hide();
  $nom3.hide();
  $nom4.hide();
  $nom5.hide();

}
```